# Using multiple if conditions with `str.format()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.

I check score1,2,3 columns and print the respective subjects. I can compare 2 columns and print the respective text.

How do I include a different column?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = {'Sub1':['A','B','C','D','E'],
            'Sub2':['F','G','H','I','J'],
            'Sub3':['K','L','M','N','O'],
    'S_score1': [1, 0, 0, 6,0], 
    'F_score1' : [0, 1,0,0,0],
    'L_score1' : [1,2,3,0,4],
    'S_score2': [0, 0, 0, 6,0], 
    'F_score2' : [0, 1,0,0,0],
    'L_score2' : [1,2,3,0,4],
    'S_score3': [0, 0, 0, 6,0], 
    'F_score3' : [0, 1,0,0,0],
    'L_score3' : [1,2,3,0,4]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Sub1','Sub2','Sub3','S_score1', 'F_score1','L_score1','S_score2', 'F_score2','L_score2','S_score3', 'F_score3','L_score3'])

def S_text(f):
    s_text = "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub1']) if f['S_score1'] >= 1 else "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub2'])
    return s_text

def F_text(f):
    f_text = "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub1']) if f['F_score1'] >= 1 else "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub2'])
    return f_text

def L_text(f):
    l_text = "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub1']) if f['L_score1'] >= 1 else "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub2'])
    return l_text

df2['s_text'] = df2.apply(S_text, axis=1)
df2['f_text'] = df2.apply(F_text, axis=1)
df2['l_text'] = df2.apply(L_text, axis=1)
```

and i am looking like like below type comparison but this giving error. 
basically i want if 2 columns satisfy the conditions(scores>=1) i wanted to print 2 respective subjects. if 3 columns satisfy the conditions(scores>=1) and i wanted to print 3 subjects in text like below for 2 conditions. is there any alternative way to compare 3 columns and print the text.

```
def S_text(f):
    s_text = "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub1']) if f['S_score1'] >= 1 
    elif  f['S_score2'] >= 1 "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub2']) 
    elif f['S_score3'] >=1 "You have scored on {}" .format(f['Sub3']) 
    elif f['S_score1'] >=1 and f['S_score2']>=1 "You have scored on {} {}" .format(f['Sub1'], f['Sub2'])
    elif f['S_score1'] >=1 and f['S_score3']>=1 "You have scored on {} {}" .format(f['Sub1'], f['Sub3'])
    elif f['S_score2'] >=1 and f['S_score3']>=1 "You have scored on {} {}" .format(f['Sub2'], f['Sub3'])
    elif f['S_score1'] >=1 and f['S_score2']>=1 and f['S_score3']>=1 "You have scored on {} {} {}" .format(f['Sub1'],f['Sub2'], f['Sub3'])
    return s_text
```

wanted output:

[image: output]

Comment: why flag python2 and 3? are you _using_ both? Is your problem related to working on one and not the other and you need to for both?

Comment: any version is fine with me.thats why i tagged both.

Comment: i have untagged 2.7 version.Thanks

Comment: logic here is unclear , could you please explain more  ？

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @W-B  i have inserted expected output.

Comment: @Setop expected output attached.

Comment: You are using `str.format()` which is not the same as f-strings https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

Your df does not match the expected results, it should be like this to match your output:

```
raw_data = {'Sub1':['A','B','C','D','E'],
            'Sub2':['F','G','H','I','J'],
            'Sub3':['K','L','M','N','O'],
    'S_score1': [1, 0, 0, 6,0], 
    'F_score1' : [0, 1,0,0,0],
    'L_score1' : [1,2,3,0,4],
    'S_score2': [0, 1, 0, 6,0], 
    'F_score2' : [0, 1,0,0,0],
    'L_score2' : [1,2,3,0,4],
    'S_score3': [0, 1, 0, 6,0], 
    'F_score3' : [0, 1,0,0,0],
    'L_score3' : [1,2,3,0,4]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Sub1','Sub2','Sub3','S_score1', 'F_score1','L_score1','S_score2', 'F_score2','L_score2','S_score3', 'F_score3','L_score3'])
```

I added a loop to deal with the different labels. This time is matching the output.

```
import re
letters = ['S', 'F', 'L']
for letter in letters:
    for row in range(0, len(df2)):
        df_ = df2[[letter+'_score1', letter+'_score2', letter+'_score3']].iloc[row:row+1,0:3]
        row_string = ''
        for col in df_.columns:
            if df_[col][row] >= 1:
                row_string = row_string + ', '+ str(df2.iloc[row][df_.columns.get_loc(col)])
            row_string = re.sub(r'^,', '', row_string)
        if row_string == '':
            df2.loc[row:,letter+'_text'] = 'You have not Scored any subject'
        else:
            df2.loc[row:,letter+'_text'] = 'You have scored on' + row_string
display(df2))


    Sub1    Sub2    Sub3    S_score1    F_score1    L_score1    S_score2    F_score2    L_score2    S_score3    F_score3    L_score3    S_text  F_text  L_text
0   A   F   K   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   You have scored on A    You have not Scored any subject You have scored on A, F, K
1   B   G   L   0   1   2   1   1   2   1   1   2   You have scored on G, L You have scored on B, G, L  You have scored on B, G, L
2   C   H   M   0   0   3   0   0   3   0   0   3   You have not Scored any subject You have not Scored any subject You have scored on C, H, M
3   D   I   N   6   0   0   6   0   0   6   0   0   You have scored on D, I, N  You have not Scored any subject You have not Scored any subject
4   E   J   O   0   0   4   0   0   4   0   0   4   You have not Scored any subject You have not Scored any subject You have scored on E, J, O
```

I am sure there are easier ways to do this too.

Comment: this is not working in other datframes. i am getting Keyerror:0 on this line   if df_[col][row] >= 1:

Comment: This only work in the data frame you provided. It is basically taking the column numbers in the de created with the scores columns and applying that to the original data frame where the first three columns are the ones you want to get the information from. You will need to adjust that to the code I provided. Also, add the input and output data frames to the question. I was assuming you were working on the one provided.

Comment: @KumarAK the expected output does not match the data in the data frame for the S_scores. Check my edits to my answer.